# Including a non-Mavenized dependency so it works with maven-shade-plugin

Tags: jar, dependencies, maven-2, maven-shade-plugin

I want to include [GData Client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/), which doesn't use Maven, as a dependency into my Maven project. It ships as a bunch of JAR files.

Additionaly, I use [Maven Shade Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to build an executable JAR without any external dependencies (with the default configuration, no renaming/including/excluding/transforming of dependencies).

How can I do that?

(Just adding the JARs as resources wouldn't work, since the Shade plugin must extract them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you want to check the maven docs on [installing 3rd party jars](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

Once installed into your local maven repository, shade should be able to use them like any other dependency.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer if you don't want to install the JARs in your repository for whatever reason: [Add a dependency in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396245/add-a-dependency-in-maven/765032#765032)

Comment: System scope replaces a problem rather than solving it. Its use of absolute paths tends to cause problems when dealing with more than one developer or when trying to use a CI server. Installing the jar in an company or group wide repository should be preferred.

Comment: You can use properties in the path, so there is no need to make it absolute.

Comment: maven-shade-plugin will not include system scoped jars in the shaded jar, so unfortunately this does not work