# Maven cannot find JAR

Tags: java, maven, jave

Recently I tried to develop an interface for my group. My service runs and works well on my local machine, but when trying to use **Maven Compile** in IDEA, the compilation fails and tells me it cannot find my JAR package. The JAR package I use is JAVE (Java Audio Video Encoder), which was manually added into my CLASSPATH. I know Maven cannot find JAR package without adding dependency to pom, but I can't find the Maven dependency for JAVE, it seems that they only provide a JAR package for users. [JAVE HomePage](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/index.php)

So in this case, what should I do if I want to successfully compile my code using Maven? I need to deploy my service in the future, so manually adding JAR package to my CLASSPATH instead of adding dependency to pom is definitely not acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the artefact to either your local or a remote maven repo or you could use it as a system-scoped dependency (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2177417/9705485 or http://roufid.com/3-ways-to-add-local-jar-to-maven-project/ for examples)

Answer (score 1):

You can install a maven jar locally using:

```
mvn install:install-file
   -Dfile=<path-to-file>
   -DgroupId=<group-id>
   -DartifactId=<artifact-id>
   -Dversion=<version>
   -Dpackaging=<packaging>
   -DgeneratePom=true
```