# Including jar-file in the web application maven

Tags: java, tomcat, maven

I'm new to Java development, here is the question:
I have generated the web application 
`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=webapp -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp`
, then i have added `java.com.mycompany.app` folder with the simple `App.java` file.
By the command `mvn package tomcat:deploy` in my localhost:8080/manager i can see my web app, but how can I add my jar file in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- When adding a class in `src/main/java`, Maven compiles it and ensures it gets copied into your `WEB-INF/classes` directory — so no need to do anything.  So your class `com.mycompany.app.App` should have been picked up by Maven, compiled and copied into `WEB-INF/classes` (you should be able to verify this in the `target/` folder).
- If you want to add another jar file into your war file, you need to [add this jar as a Maven dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396245/add-a-dependency-in-maven) in your `pom.xml` file.

Comment: I've done two of that steps, what will i do next? 'mvn package tomcat:deploy'? there is nothing in there

Comment: @fen1ksss  What do you mean, there is nothing in there?

Comment: mb i'm not sure what to expect, but i want my webapp in localhost:8080/manager work like a console loading for example System.out.println( "Hello World!!!" ); from my App.java - file

Comment: @fen1ksss No.  If you deploy `webapp` in Tomcat, you will access your application on http://localhost:8080/webapp.  `App.java` will do something only if it is a Servlet, or something else that gets executed on the server.  A Java class on its own will not do anything unless called.

Comment: so, i suppose to make a servlet to load "Hello world"?

Comment: @fen1ksss The webapp should already say “Hello World”, as it creates a default JSP page; but if you want to create a class that displays “Hello World” either in the browser or on the console, yes, you’ll need a Servlet.