# What is the wrong with my dependency definition?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example.cassandra</groupId>
<artifactId>simple-client</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.1.0</version>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
   <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
      <configuration>
         <mainClass>com.example.cassandra.Client</mainClass>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
 </project>
```

My java file

```
 package com.example.cassandra;

 import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;

 public class Client
 {
   // private Cluster cluster;

      public static void main(String a[])
      {
         System.out.println("I am in");
      }
  }
```

I compiled it using

```
  mvn -e compile
```

it says

```
  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler- 
     plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project simple-client:   
     Compilation failure
  [ERROR] /cassandra/src/main/java/com/example/cassandra/Client.java:[3,31] 
     error: package com.datastax.driver.core does not exist
  [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
     org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to  
     execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler- 
     plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project simple-client:   
     Compilation failure
     /cassandra/src/main/java/com/example/cassandra/Client.java:[3,31]  
     error: package com.datastax.driver.core does not exist
```

I understand that `dependency jar` is `improperly added` since it complains package doesnot exist. Where  do i add that dependency so that my code will compile and tun successfully?

[For more info](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/1.0/java-driver/quick_start/qsSimpleClientCreate_t.html) I am referring this site to run this example

Structure of the project

```
  Cassandra
     pom.xml
     src
        main
          java
            com
              example
                cassandra
                  Client.java
```

I am running these commands from Cassandra directory that is where pom.xml presents

Comment: Please, show structure of your project, which your are trying to compile. May be folder /cassandra/src/main/java/com/example/cassandra/ does not exists.

Comment: Could you try installing this dependency? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396245/add-a-dependency-in-maven

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes i am trying to add this dependancy.

Comment: Remove `<scope>test</scope>` in your Maven dependency and see if compile goal works.

Comment: Thanks @BuhakeSindi It works. Will you please tell me what scope should i give so that it ll be present at compile and runtime

Comment: Use compile which is the default scope so you may leave it out safely.

Comment: @GopsAB the default scope is compile - i recomend to have a look at the Maven Reference http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: I did update my post showing what `scope` means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to the dependency scope you specified. By not specifying the scope, the default is `compile`.

From [Maven Documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope):

> Dependency scope is used to limit the transitivity of a dependency,
>   and also to affect the classpath used for various build tasks.
>
> There are 6 scopes available:
>
> - **compile:** This is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project.
>     Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.
> - **provided:** This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For
>     example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise
>     Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related
>     Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides
>     those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and
>     test classpath, and is not transitive.
> - **runtime:** This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime
>     and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath.
> - **test:** This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal use of the application, and is only available for the test
>     compilation and execution phases.
> - **system:** This scope is similar to provided except that you have to provide the JAR which contains it explicitly. The artifact is
>     always available and is not looked up in a repository.
> - **import:** (only available in Maven 2.0.9 or later) This scope is only used on a dependency of type pom in the 
>     section. It indicates that the specified POM should be replaced with
>     the dependencies in that POM's  section. Since
>     they are replaced, dependencies with a scope of import do not actually
>     participate in limiting the transitivity of a dependency.

Comment: I read this already. I thought test would be the most suitable choice. Will you please tell me why my code doesn't compile? Because `is only available for the test compilation and execution phases' i see this line in the doc.

Comment: Maven works with a goal and you can specify some scope is dependent on some build goals. Dependencies with test scope will not be included in compile goal and you're doing a compile so the dependency was not available.