# Classpath in IntelliJ

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea

Hi I am new to Java Development, especially IntelliJ. From a colleague, who uses Eclipse I received a Maven Spring Project. It worked fine, it would download all dependencies. However as soon as I started the server it would tell me, that files which I declared as resources couldn't be found.

So I looked into my project settings and added it as the dependency:

[image]

But this does only work when I set the Dependencies storage format to Eclipse.

How can I change this to IntelliJ's format?

Or better, what is the difference between the classpath files from Eclipse and the .iml files from IntelliJ? Maybe I just need to adjust on IML file to take my resources.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Maven project, you should add dependency using the pom.xml. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396245/add-a-dependency-in-maven) is one of the samples.

Comment: Please post your clarification question as a comment to the question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wished I could. Still need another 30 reputation. Anyway, thanks. I will try to work on those i can answer :)