# Using Jsoup in Java - get not accessible

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to use Jsoup in a Java project. For this I have included the Jar File in Referenced Libraries. However, I keep getting 'The type org.jsoup.Jsoup is not accessible' error

[image]

> The type org.jsoup.Jsoup is not accessible

Answer (score 1):

You want to add a 3rd party lib to a Maven project, if I understand correctly, which is already answered here: [Add a dependency in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396245/add-a-dependency-in-maven)

However, in your case, there is no need to install the jar in your local Maven repository as Jsoup is already available on Maven: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.15.3

Don't forget to add `requires org.jsoup;` to your `module-info.java`.