# I installed J connector driver and i create database connection and i still has exception nosuitabledriverfound

Tags: java

I have the code

```java
package com.mycompany.mavenproject1;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

 /**
 *
 * @author aleksandar
 */
public class Mavenproject1{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String uri = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
        try{
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(uri, "root", "Miskin@1982");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
       
        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I have in MySQL database test.

I have installed com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver in my Connector/J driver and I make a connection, but exception is still thrown.

my pom.xml is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <exec.mainClass>com.mycompany.mavenproject1.Mavenproject1</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Where did you install your driver?  Is it in the project classpath?

Comment: Hello, the correct url for MySQL is "jdbc.mysql://..."

Comment: yes it is a mistake mysql should i wrote

Comment: i try like that but no solution

Comment: my driver is on my desktop

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: i went in neatbeans services and in drivers column add drivers file(s) and i find the driver

Comment: You have to add the dependency to the driver in the maven `pom.xml` file, can you show your pom.xml? And exactly how are you running the program? The driver needs to be in the classpath. If you are using a maven project to run it, that gets done by adding the dependency

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

Comment: <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <exec.mainClass>com.mycompany.mavenproject1.Mavenproject1</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>
</project>

Comment: Aleksandar - Thank you for the updates, but please [edit] your question and add relevant updates there - not in comments (and please take a look at how to [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your additions, for readability).

Comment: See also [Add a dependency in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396245/add-a-dependency-in-maven) - and see [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j) for some recent drivers.

Comment: How do you run your application? Likely you're running it in a way without the driver on the classpath.

Comment: solved hurraaa!

Comment: i add dependeces and i change pom.xml