# Is there any extension/plugin to maven allowing user to write "mvn add mylib" in command line?

Tags: maven, command-line-interface

I do like maven, but a colleague recently mentionned a missing element.
As far as I know, it is not possible to write `mvn (SEARCHED)add commons-lang` (where `(SEARCHED)` is a plugin or extension) to have the commons-lang dependency added to the pom.

Do you know any solution to do such a thing ?

Comment: This is technically possible (anyone can write custom plugins for maven), but I doubt the usability of this. For maven to be able to discover this custom plugin, you would already need to declare a dependency on this plugin, defeating the purpose a little. Since you are already editing the pom manually to declare the dependency on the plugin, you could instead just paste the dependency info for the library you want to add and be done.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the Maven dependency plugin, which can copy, unpack, or install artifacts from local or remote repositories. You can find more details and examples in the following link:
[Apache Maven Dependency Plugin – Usage](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html). Another way is to use an IDE such as STS or IntelliJ IDEA, which can help you add dependencies to your pom.xml file.

You can find some instructions in these links:

[Add a dependency in Maven - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396245/add-a-dependency-in-maven)

[Maven dependencies | IntelliJ IDEA Documentation - JetBrains.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-dependencies.html)